# Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I've been working on my first Laravel program and then I encountered an error about Base_Control in which I changed to BaseControl (I was actually following a tutorial and in his example he used Base_Control) where he doesn't seem to have any problem.

Plus the tutorial was dated march 2012 so I noticed that we have difference in our project and the way he first made it. Anyway, after changing to BaseControl another error showed up.

> Class authors does not exist.

And laravel is pointing out this line: `helloLaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php`.

```php
if ($concrete instanceof Closure)
{
    return $concrete($this, $parameters);
}

$reflector = new \ReflectionClass($concrete);
```

Also does it have a connection to the BaseController error?

Comment: your tutorial was for laravel3 and you are using laravel4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question is solved.
i got some naming issues helloLaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
has nothing to do with the error it was my Controller files.. I've figured it out.
i think that's the difference between the previous versions of Laravel and the latest.
since Laravel4 uses CamelCase instead of those with '_' i changed the names of my Controller as well as my class and match them with the ones in my Routes.php